# Unable to access web application deployed on jboss from other system connected via lan

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have deployed my webapplication on jboss. My colleagues are not able to access same appication from there system. Our systems are connected through LAN. This application is working fine at my side. When we try to run it from other system its throwing message as

Error:

The connection has timed out
The server at 190.185.0.137 is taking too long to respond.

I tried to start jboss with command: 
run.bat -b 190.185.0.137

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks..

Comment: Can your colleagues telnet on the your IP and port number where JBoss is running ?

Comment: Then you surely do not have a JBoss problem :).

Comment: I have started working with tomcat for now.. I will try to resolve this issue later.. Thanks for your reply :) If I face issue I will discus with you people..

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help if still facing this issue.

I am using JBoss eap 6.1 and faced the same problem. So, I just had to enable the checkbox "*Listen on all interfaces to allow remote web connections*" in the *Server Behaviour* Section

Answer (score 0):

Try `run.bat -b 0.0.0.0` That will bind to every IP, just in case.

Also worth checking that they can `Ping` you?

And while you are at it, check if JBoss has actually bound to the correct ip on the correct port with `netstat -an`
You should see an entry on port 8080 (Or whatever port you are running it on) for JBoss

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I tried this too.. but its still the same.. They can ping me..

Comment: netstat -an

  TCP    190.185.0.137:8080      192.168.0.37:50000     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    190.185.0.137:8080      192.168.0.37:50001     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    190.185.0.137:8080     190.185.0.137:50002     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    190.185.0.137:8080     190.185.0.137:50003     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    190.185.0.137:8080     190.185.0.137:50004     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    190.185.0.137:8080     190.185.0.137:50005     TIME_WAIT

Comment: Windows Firewall?  Other Firewalls?  Doesn't sounds like a JBoss issue to be honest...

Comment: You don't have any embedded resources on your page, hard coded to 127.0.0.1, or locahost or any other IP address that might be different from their position on the network or anything do you?  Can they get tot eh JBoss Console / admin stuff on your box from theirs?

Comment: I have started working with tomcat for now.. I will try to resolve this issue later.. Thanks for your reply :) If I face issue I will discus with you people..

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your firewall allows incoming connections from remote machines on the port where JBoss is running. As mentioned earlier, this does not seem to be a JBoss problem.